# Estimating direct and total effects in path model (mediation)

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, path-model

[image]

I am testing mediation effects in this path model. How should I define the (1) direct and (2) total effects in this model?

Is the below correct?
(1) Direct= c1*c2
(2) Total= (c1*c2)+a1*d21*b2

Comment: You have direct effects from X1 to M2 (A2), M1 to X3 (B1). Which indirect effects are you interested in?

Comment: I am actually interested in testing whether the direct path between x1-x3 remains significant after (1) accounting for the indirect effects of M1, M2, and "d21" path and (2) accounting for X2 (time 3). So to answer your question, indirect effects of interest are (1) a1*b1 (2) a2*b2 (3) a1*d21*b2. Just not sure how I can specify the traditional "c" path between x1-x2-x3 when an extra time point is included to account for change happening between x1 and x2 (to conclude that the real change happening between x2 and x3 is mediated by the mediators.

Comment: There is no direct path from x1 to x3 in your model though.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the party but if anyone finds this relevant:

Direct effects are all those that are simply depicted by each arrow. For example, A1 is a direct effect of X1 on M1. Similarly, C2 is a direct effect of X2 on X3.

Indirect effect is the effect of one variable on another through one of more mediators. The way to think about it is that mediators are mechanisms through which one variable affects another. For example, the indirect effect of X1 on X3 through mediator M1 and M2 is 
A1*D21*B2.

Finally, total effect is a total of all effects of one variable on another, which includes all direct effects and mediated effects if they are present. For example, the total effect of X1 on X3 = (A1*D21*B2) + (A1*B1) + (A2*B1) + (A2*B2) + (C1*C2)